# SQL Automation by Column Values Not Time

Tags: sql, automation, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a ~20 million row dataset for addresses in the US. Currently I perform a query for each state's addresses by manually changing the WHERE statement to the proper State Abbreviation (e.g. WHERE STATE_ABV= 'NY').
I have to do queries state-by-state because I export these files as csvs which has a low row limit and cannot handle the enitre US dataset.

Is there a way to automate the process so after each run the query would be exported as a csv, the WHERE statement would be changed to the next State Abbreviation, and then the proccess run again? I would like to have 50 csvs saved somewhere (one for each state) by the end of the automation.

All my searcing about automation discussed doing recurring queries based on time not variables so I understand if this is not possible.

The software I am using is SQL Developer

Thanks as always

Comment: Just to clarify: which database? MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle ... What you want to do is definitely possible but the specifics will depend on which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I agree with Peter, `SELECT DISTINCT STATE_ABV FROM ...` will give you all abbreviations, throw a loop into the mix and you might have the correct recipe for a solution.